# What is the difference between "How about" vs "What about"?

Tags: interrogatives

Can anyone tell me the difference between ***How about*** and ***What about*** in the following sentences?

> What should I say: **What about** her or **How about** her ?

And,

> Should I say **What about** playing cards or **How about** playing cards?

Comment: They are interchangeable in the example you've given. Both mean "Why don't we play cards!" or "Let's play cards" -- an invitation or suggestion.

Comment: They may be _practically_ interchangeable, but the mental experience of a native speaker hearing them is slightly different.  https://english.stackexchange.com/a/460743/443

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is some difference in usage between [how about](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/how-about) and [what about](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/what-about).

If you are planning something with a friend and you want to raise some potential problem, you would only use **what about**- effectively as a short form for **what shall we do about...**. If you want to suggest a new idea or a possible solution to a problem, you can use either **what about** or **how about**.

> Person A: **How about/what about** going sailing tomorrow! -*suggestion*
>   Person B: Nice idea, but **what about** the kids? - *potential problem*
>   Person A: Could we get somebody to baby sit?
>   Person B: **How about/what about** your neighbour's daughter? - *suggested solution*

Looking at your sentences:

> **what about/how about** her? -*if she's a suggestion or a solution*
>   **what about** her? - *if she's a potential problem.*

.

> **What about/how about** playing cards? -*playing cards is a suggestion*

Comment: It sounds good in theory, but in practice I don't buy the idea that ***What** about X?* is more appropriate than ***How** about X?* if X is a *problem*, rather than a *suggestion/solution*. Google Books claims 136,000 instances of [***How** about the cost*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22how+about+the+cost%22), but only 19,100 [***What** about the cost*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22what+about+the+cost%22), and I'd say ***cost*** is *always* a problem, never a solution.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's curious: with Ngram it's clearly the other way round... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+about+the+cost%2C+what+about+the+cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chow%20about%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20about%20the%20cost%3B%2Cc0 What's more interesting is that if you separate out BrE and AmE, **none** of the **how about the cost** references are BrE: and I am writing from a BrE perspective.

Comment: *Very* strange. Being British myself, I suppose I must have a BrE perspective too, but I don't think the lack of BrE **how about the cost** in your NGram necessarily implies any US/UK usage split (there are actually only 32 instances *in total*). Looking at my first comment again, I can see it *might* be taken as implying I thought the *opposite* distinction applied, but actually what I meant was I think the two forms are effectively *interchangeable* (though individual speakers may have preferences). Which I still think, though I don't understand those conflicting Books / NGrams results.

Comment: I don't know if they're enough to be statistically significant, but there are 7 hits in Books for [how about the downside](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22how+about+the+downside%22), against a "guestimated" 2100 for [what about the downside](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22what+about+the+downside%22) (which turns out to be just 25 if you scroll to the third page of results). In which context it *may* be relevant that ***downside*** had negligible currency until a few decades ago, and is more AmE than BrE even today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I have added links to my answer that back up my assertion that **what about** is more likely to be used for "what shall we do about" situations (see item 4 in **what about**).

Comment: Well, I don't intend to vote one way or the other, and I've made my point in the first comment here. We're trying to establish usage preferences for a primarily *spoken* expression using *written* sources anyway. But even if it could be proved that the *majority* of speakers actually observe the distinction you make, that certainly doesn't imply the "less common" choice would be in any sense "incorrect". And I honestly can't see how those two definitions support taking a strong position on this one.

Comment: @JavaLatte, <How about the kids?> and <How about her?> sounds ok above, no?

Comment: @Pacerier, which 'above' are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 scenarios in total: objection, suggestion and caring about. You would only use **what about** in first case. "How about/what about" are interchangeable for other two situations.

Let's say A and B are discussing the vacation.

> A: **How about/what about** a vacation to Hawaii? (suggestion)
>
> B: Great idea, but **what about** the dogs? (objection, potential problem)
>
> A: My parents will look after them.

When the friends are Hawaii, they drink a lot at party.

> A: I am so drunk. **How about/what about** you? (caring about, asking about what someone is doing or feeling)