# "look after", "take care of" and "take after"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In my another [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/239810/109190) I said

> A: How about/what about a vacation to Hawaii? (suggestion)
>
> B: Great idea, but what about the dogs? (objection, potential problem)
>
> A: My parents will **look after** them.

I am not very I should use **look after** or **take care of**.

A [post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/take-care-of-vs-look-after.1113376/) says

> 'Look after' can suggest to keep someone from trouble, watching over them, attending to their basic needs such as hunger and shelter, as a sort of guardian. 'Take care of' perhaps has a more maternal feel to it in the sense of protection, love in certain contexts, and of course, care.

How about "take after"? Are "look after", "take care of" and "take after" interchangeable in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. "Take after" is an idiom that means "resembles". Suppose a child looks like her parent. Then you could say that "She takes after her mother". For the context of the vacation and dogs, you could use "look after", "take care of", "see to".