# What about you or how about you

Tags: american-english, conversation

I was wondering, if we want to ask someone their answer on something in this kind of context below:

A: How did you feel after graduating from high school?
B: To be honest, I felt nothing. It was not that special. **What about you** or **how about you**?

Comment: In this particular context, they are interchangeable.

Comment: These seem related, but I'm hesitant to say they are duplicates: [What is the difference between “How about” vs “What about”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103193/what-is-the-difference-between-how-about-vs-what-about); [When should we use “how about x(something\someone )” and when should we use “what about x”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/256823/when-should-we-use-how-about-xsomething-someone-and-when-should-we-use-wha)

Comment: You've asked a few questions that seem to have duplicates. I recommend that you search our site for related posts (e.g. [what about how about](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+about+how+about)). You may find your answers that way. If not, include that research in your post as it could clarify your problem. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

How about and what about ... Google has them both as: used to make an offer or a suggestion; or to enquire for information. I have heard them both used in this way this last 70 years, so believe you may use either.

Comment: What is this Google that has expressions? The dictionary that appears top of a Google search when I enter say _stenographer_ ... _meaning_ is Lexico.